# Asymptotics in recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion

I have an recurrence relation $T(n)= n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(n-k)+T(k)) = O(3^n)$ and $T(1)=1$.

I self study on asymptotic and recurrence example. Lots of example I read but this one is very strange!

How we can solve this recurrence? i.e: reach to answer.

Comment: It seems $T(0)$ is in that recurrence.  Is it what you want?  Also, $T(n)$ is on the left and on the right, so they will cancel.

Comment: Obviously, it should be $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since by definition $$
T(n)= n+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (T(n-k)+T(k)) = n + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)
$$
you can rewrite, for any $n$, that
$$
T(n+1)= n + 1 + 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} T(k) = 1+ 2T(n)+ \underbrace{n+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} T(k)}_{T(n)}
= 1+3T(n)
$$
This is easily solved: $T(1)=1$ and $T(n+1)=3T(n)+1$ have the solution
$$
\boxed{\forall n\geq 1,\qquad T(n) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 3^{n}-\frac{1}{2}} \tag{$\ast$}
$$
which is indeed $O(3^n)$.

You can derive $(\ast)$ yourself by setting
$S(n) = T(n)+\frac{1}{2}$, so that $S(1) = \frac{3}{2}$ and observing that then
$$S(n+1) = T(n+1)+\frac{1}{2}=3T(n)+1+\frac{1}{2} = 3\left(T(n)+\frac{1}{2}\right) = 3S(n)$$ this is a geometric progression, so $S(n) = 3^{n-1}S(1)$. This gives you $T(n)$.

Comment: Glad it helped! @BettyAndersson

Answer (score 0):

I'll start from assumption $T(1)=1$ and $T(n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}(T(i)+T(n-i))$.

It's easy to see, that $T(n)=2\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}T(i)$. Elaborating partial cases gives hypothesis $T(n)=2\cdot 3^{n-2}$, when $n\geqslant 2$:

$$\begin{array}{l}
T(2)=T(1)+ T(1) = 2 \cdot3^{0} \\
T(3)=2\big(T(1)+ T(2)\big) = 2 \cdot3^{1} \\
T(4)=2\big(T(1)+ T(2)+ T(3)\big) = 2 \cdot3^{2} \\
\cdots \\
T(n)=2\big(T(1)+ T(2)+ \cdots+ T(n-1) \big)=2 \cdot3^{n-2}\ (\text{hypothesis})\\
\cdots \\
\end{array}$$

General formula can be proved, for example, by **induction**:
$$T(n+1)=2T(1)+ 2\big( T(2)+ \cdots+ T(n) \big) = \\
=2T(1)+ 2\big(2\cdot3^{0} + 2 \cdot3^{1}+ \cdots+ 2 \cdot3^{n-2}\big)= \\
=2+2\frac{3^{n-1}-1}{3-1} = 2 \cdot 3^{n-1}$$
At last is clear, that $T(n) \in O(3^{n})$.

Comment: exactly my question in "partial cases" !! middle steps not very clear for me.

Comment: Write, please, which one you would like to see and I'll add it.

Comment: Added. Feel free to ask more if/when you'll need it.

Comment: I don't think your result is correct -- didn't you miss the additive $n$ in the recurrence relation?

Comment: (The OP's recurrence relation is $T(n) = n+\dots$, you are missing that $n$ in what you are solving.)

Comment: Of course you are correct, thanks. Additive $+n$ is missing and de facto I solved another recurrence. What I wrote is correct, but is not OP recurrence. I can delete it, if it will be counted appropriate. Anyway, hope, my example/idea helped others.

Comment: Modifying your answer to use the same technique (but for the right relation) might be the best course of action? That could be useful to many, esp. since not all such recurrence relations can be solved exactly (my own answer does not generalize that much.)